Why are these tables different? (R, str() or exporting .txt or modifying the difference)
I'm loading some txt files with readMappings() in the topGO package.
In the loading files, I've got this difference between two files;
First one is from the example data of 'topGO'
> geneID2GO \<- readMappings(file = system.file("example/geneid2go.map", package = "topGO") 

List of 6 $
068724: chr \[1:5\] "GO:0005488" "GO:0003774" "GO:0001539" "GO:0006935" ... $
119608: chr \[1:6\] "GO:0005634" "GO:0030528" "GO:0006355" "GO:0045449" ... $
049239: chr \[1:13\] "GO:0016787" "GO:0017057" "GO:0005975" "GO:0005783" ... $
067829: chr \[1:16\] "GO:0045926" "GO:0016616" "GO:0000287" "GO:0030145" ... $
106331: chr \[1:10\] "GO:0043565" "GO:0000122" "GO:0003700" "GO:0005634" ... $
214717: chr \[1:7\] "GO:0004803" "GO:0005634" "GO:0008270" "GO:0003677" ...

the other one is from annotation file (.txt) that I'd exported using
"write.table(x, file = "y", sep "\\t", row.names = FALSE)

List of 6 $
"locus_tag"    : chr ""Ontology"" $
"CDO30_RS00005": chr NA $
"CDO30_RS00010": chr \[1:3\] ""GO:0009306" "GO:0015450" "GO:0005886"" $ 
"CDO30_RS00015": chr NA $
"CDO30_RS00020": chr NA $
"CDO30_RS00025": chr NA $

I read the two files, str(head(files))
and they were displayed differently, the first rows,
Does anyone know why the two files are different?
Did I make exporting txt file bad?
Please help let me make this right.
Thank you
I changed couple of things when the files were exported in txt.
However, it doesn't work.

Looks like a better fit for https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ It appears to be a question that presumes knowledge of a lot of stuff that is not really programming (unless, of course, you think genetics and proteomics is just programming.)
